# how to change <p>'s position inside a <div>?

Tags: html

I got a

tag inside a :

```
#in .css file
div.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
}

#in .html file
<div class="box">
    <p>Here</p>
</div>
```

and it looks like this:

```
------------
|          |
|   Here   |
|          |
------------
```

but I want to put `<p>` at the bottom of `<div>`, like this:

```
------------
|          |
|          |
|   Here   |
------------
```

How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add this

```
div.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    position:relative;
}
div.box p{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: what is the `relative` in `div.box` for?

Comment: @Alcott It does nothing in this case, but when the containers height is explicit there can be a problem with 'bottom' attribute

Comment: @Alcott make child of the div relative to the div not the document

Comment: @mgraph,well, actually according to the w3's doc, `position: relative` means `The element is positioned relative to its normal position'. It seems that, `relative` doesn't have anything to do with child, right?

Comment: @Alcott if you remove it the <p> tag will be relative to the document that will show the <p> tag in the bottom of your document because it have a absolute position

Comment: @mgraph 'relative' doesn't mean that child's position is relative to its container. it means its position that is adjusted by top/left/right/bottom attributes is relative to the original position of itself.

Comment: @Sang yes Sang am little bad in explanation

Comment: @mgraph, then how does `relative` affect div's child?

Comment: @Alcott that affect if only they have (position) property

Comment: When you set `position: relative;` it means that any element with `position: absolute;` contained within will set its `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` CSS properties according to the bounds of the element with relative positioning. Since `div.box` has `position: relative;` that means that if you set another element inside of it with `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;` then that element will be in the top right corner of `div.box`.